# mix SATA 3 and SATA 2 HDD in RAID 0

Tags: sata, raid-0

I have MegaRAID `6Gb/s` RAID controller (LSI 9261-8i). Now I have an `RAID 0` array that consists from 4 reliable enterprise server HDDs (WD Re) that support `SATA 3`. I need to extend this array (to increase IO speed ). But I can't find the same RE server disks. But I can get disks of the this family (WD Re) that support `SATA 2 (3 Gb/s` instead of 6 Gb/s) - the rest is the same (size, buffer size, also server reliable new disks). Will they slowdown the array if I add those 3 Gb SATA 2 disks to array with SATA 3 disks? Or in this configuration the difference in interface and nominal speed has no difference?

Comment: In terms of bandwidth, 3Gb/s probably won't be a noticeable bottleneck for rotational drive. However, NCQ was also introduced in SATA 3.0, so under some circumstances it could still be slightly inferior than using a SATA 3.0 drive. I don't think it would be a significant difference though (especially when in real life instead of benchmarks).

Comment: @Tom Yan Thank you. Better stay with SATA 3 - my disks are loaded ~90 %

Comment: Btw, this might be of your interest: https://www.extremetech.com/computing/309389-western-digital-seagate-reportedly-shipping-slow-smr-drives-without-informing-customers (no idea if the SATA 2.0 model you were looking at are more likely to be PMR though)

Comment: @Tom Yan Thank you. I think they CMR/PMR because RE demonstrate good write performance. In comparison with Seagate Archive (that is known as SMR) RE disks much faster.